# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in project

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]

I have created an attendence system in visual basic 6.0, an error is coming in it, one entry is happening but the other entry is not happening, the error is telling, please tell me its solution. 
thanks

```
 rsg.Open "select * from advanceentry where date1='" & Format$(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy") & "' ", cd2, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `date1` is a Date\Time field, then you don't need the single quotes, and should use `Format` rather than `Format$`. Try:

```
rsg.Open "select * from advanceentry where date1=" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "d/M/yyyy"), cd2, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating, a date value must be formatted as an expression having the ISO sequence and be wrapped in octothorpes.
Also, it is convenient to have the SQL in a variable of its own, and the `Text` property is only available when the control has focus:

```vb
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "select sum(advalue) from advanceentry where date1 >= #" & Format(Me!DTPicker1.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and date1 <= #" & Format(Me!DTPicker2.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and ename = '" & L_ename.Calue & "'"
rs_pay.Open Sql, cd_pay, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Sql = "select ename,date1,advalue,date2 from advanceentry where date1 >= #" & Format(Me!DTPicker1.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and date1 <= #" & Format(Me!DTPicker2.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and ename = '" & L_ename.Value & "' order by date2"
adv_pay.Open Sql, cd_pay, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Then your date1 field isn't of data type DateTime.